# AWS S3 Python Boto3: Get DEEP_ARCHIVE object restore costs

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to restore AWS S3 objects that are in DEEP_ARCHIVE storage class. Based on retrieval cost, I want to decide which retrieval tier I should go for (Standard or Bulk). S3 browser helps in showing this forecast.

[image]

How to get the same using Python Boto3?

Comment: This just looks like it's calculating `price * size`. You can hard-code the price, or you can fetch it from the pricing API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/price-changes.html